# Is there any way rapidjson double string representation to be precise? Is there a possibility I am wrong regarding rapidjson workflow?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I use the following workflow to create a json file with the contents of an object:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
rapidjson::StringBuffer s;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(s);

writer.StartObject();   
writer.Double(static_cast<double>(getX())); // X is float. Cast not necessary, here for clarity    
... // some more writes
write.EndObject();

document.Parse(s.GetString());

FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
char writeBuffer[65536];
rapidjson::FileWriteStream os(fp, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::FileWriteStream> fileWriter(os);
char indent = ' '; // single space x 4
fileWriter.SetIndent(indent, 4);

document.Accept(fileWriter);

fclose(fp);
```

An X value of **"25897.12354"** becomes **"25897.123046875"** and as you can see it's not a matter of precision, the forth decimal is completely out of place.
A value of 3.1416 (as of the example in the documentation), becomes 3.1415998935699465.

I understand the "double to string converstion closest representation", but I wonder if this is the case here.

I would hate strings in place of numbers in my JSON, in order to surpass this problem and always making a custom double->string->double conversion.

I also would not use SetMaxDecimalPlaces, since it does not seem to work properly either:
my X value of 225897.12354 becomes 225897.125, while another of 25897.12354 becomes 25897.12304!

Struggling a bit with documentation and various solutions, it occured to me that probably I'm doing something wrong with the implementation.

1. Is this workflow working with rapidjson correct? Should one parse an object (its stringBuffer) initially with `s.GetString()`. Shouldn't write it directly to the filewriter?
2. Is endianess affecting the doubleToString conversion?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the wrong part of the code (without looking the forest), I've missed my usual method of opening/writing files for this project (the majority is binary files)...

Removing 'b' from:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
```

the file is written correctly...